# How to make a bookmark code for comic book image slideshows

Tags: javascript, php

So as the title says, I am having a hard time looking for and even making a code to bookmark certain pages of a comic book image slideshow, what I have for the images are:

```
<?php
      foreach($images as $image){
           echo "<img class='slides' src='$directory/$image'>";
      }
 ?>
```

How do I bookmark a specific image/page for the reader and add a button that says "Go to bookmark" once it is done?

Comment: your code doesn't seem to be at all relevant to the question

Comment: you need to add a bookmark button with specific data-attribute to each of you're slider and handle the bookmark button click event and send a ajax request to the server for bookmarking that slide.